# Activemq REST without body=

Tags: rest, activemq-classic

Is there a way to `POST` to an ActiveMQ topic without requiring `body=` ?

e.g. instead of this:

```
curl -u test:test -d "body=message" http://server:8161/api/message/testtopic?type=topic
```

use this:

```
curl -u test:test -d "message" http://server:8161/api/message/testtopic?type=topic
```

Answer (score 0):

It [turns out](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html) that specifying the `Content-Type` allows you to omit `body=`

```
curl -u test:test -d "message" -H "Content-Type: text/plain" http://server:8161/api/message/testtopic?type=topic
```